# Data Driven Pages in ArcGIS; not all pages plotting

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, data-driven-pages

I am using Data Driven Pages (DDP) in ArcGIS for Desktop 10.3. My pages are indexed with the lables "Page1", "Page2"..."Page12". However only the first ten are showing. From looking into this I am not aware of any such limit of the number of pages. See my index layer below;

```
OBJECTID *  Shape * Shape_Length    Shape_Area  PAGE
1           Polygon 3883.2122       942341.856  Page1
2           Polygon 6865.951        2912272.508 Page2
3           Polygon 6905.639        2969978.993 Page3
4           Polygon 8350.2668       4357918.976 Page4
5           Polygon 8995.8514       5008438.638 Page5
6           Polygon 5549.911        1905578.347 Page6
7           Polygon 6625.1798       2731887.094 Page7
8           Polygon 3979.3414       983396.9592 Page8
9           Polygon 8625.434        4301756.02  Page9
10          Polygon 8382.0168       4215492.372 Page10
11          Polygon 8305.8166       4290331.162 Page11
12          Polygon 9359.9188       5302510.725 Page12
```

However the last page that shows in the drawing is Page9; the other shows do not show in the Data Driven Pages Toolbar even after refreshing. See screenshot;

[image: Screenshot of DDP Toolbar]

What is the error in my setup or my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up your Data Driven Pages make sure you use a numeric field to sort your pages.  If you sort by your page name it'll sort in character order from left-to-right in your field, so 10 will come before 2 - It'll sort it Page1, Page10, Page11, Page2, Page21 etc.:

[image]

If you have a numeric field with each page number in it and set Data Driven Pages to sort on that field, your pages will sort numerically:

[image]